Estimating missing zero class probability using a zero-truncated negative binomial (polya) distribution
I have discrete data that has the zero class missing. i.e. I have frequency bins centered at $[1,2,..N]$ but no data for the bin at zero.
I have been successful in fitting a zero truncated Poisson distribution to the data by using the recursive relation:
$$  \lambda_0 = \bar{X}, \\ \lambda_{i+1} = \bar{X} \, ( 1-e^{- \lambda_i} ) ,$$
with $\bar{X}$ the sample mean and $\lambda_i$ the mean of the Poisson distribution at iteration $i$. Then the probability of the missing zero class is:
$$ \hat{P}_0 = \frac{P_0}{1-P_0} = \frac{e^{- \bar{\lambda}}}{ 1-e^{{- \bar{\lambda}}} } .$$
This method works, but in some cases the data does not follow very closely a Poisson distribution, leading to nonsensical estimates of the zero class.
My data have a small number of classes. I believe a distribution with a finite-support would be a better choice. I decided to try with a binomial distribution, and solve:
$$  p_0 = \bar{X} /N, \\ p_{i+1} = \bar{X} \, \bigg[ 1 -  (1-p_i)^N \bigg] \,/N .$$
Using the binomial leads to better estimates of the missing zero class, however I want to try fitting a negative binomial (Polya) distribution to the data. I found this paper in which they present an estimator for the zero class probability in the case of a Polya distribution. I implemented the mentioned result (eqs. 14 and 15 in paper) to infer the missing zero-class in my problem:
$$  \omega_0 = 2 \sigma^2 , \\ \omega_{i+1} = 2 \sigma^2 \, \bigg[ 1 -  (1+\omega_i)^{-\bar{X}/{2 \sigma^2}} \bigg] \,/N ,$$
but the results are wildly off.
Perhaps I am missing something? Could anyone suggest a better estimator, or pinpoint my mistake? Thank all of you!

I have derived the solution for the Negative-Binomial case, but using the standard notation, using as pdf for $x$
$$f(x|r,p)={x+r-1 \choose x} p^x (1-p)^r$$
which gives me for the conditional probability of not being able to measure $x=0$
$$f(x|r,p,x>0)={x+r-1 \choose x} \frac{p^x (1-p)^r}{1-(1-p)^r}$$
Taking the derivative of the log-likelihood with respect to $p$ and setting it to zero, gives me
$$\frac{\bar x}{p}-\frac{r}{1-p}-\frac{r (1-p)^r}{(1-p)(1-(1-p)^r)}=0$$
with $\bar x$ the sample mean. This can be recursively written as
$$p_0 = \frac{\bar x}{\bar x + r}$$
$$p_{i+1} = \frac{\bar x\left[1-(1-p_i)^r\right]}{\bar x\left[1-(1-p_i)^r\right]+r}$$
A quick test showed that this gives reasonable results. Please also notice the similarity with the Binomial case.
Regarding the overall problem, I am not sure, how you want to apply this in practice. Both the Binomial and Negative-Binomial case depend on two parameters. You assume one of them ($N$ or $r$) to be known, but I expect that it is better to find the MLE with respect to both of them.
